# Flutter unspecific Error while triggering an API request with Switch on/off events

Tags: flutter

I want to control raspberry pins with a flutter app. Therefore I build an API with Python Flask. In this case, I want to turn on and off a light with a Switch in Flutter. When the switch is toggled, I want a request to be triggered telling the API to turn the light on or off.

Switch:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool lampStatus = false;


  void toggleSwitch(bool value) async{
    if (lampStatus == false) {
      bool lampenstatus = await lampon();
      setState(() {
        lampStatus = lampenstatus;
      });
      print('Lights on');
      
    } else {
      setState(() {
        lampStatus = false;
      });
      print('Lights off');
      // await lampoff();
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(child: Text('Lights are ${lampStatus==true? 'on': 'off'}')),
            Switch(
              value: lampStatus,
              onChanged: toggleSwitch,
              activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              activeColor: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Future<bool> lampon() async {
  final response =
      await http.post(Uri.http(url, '/lampon'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final bool lampenstatus = json.decode(response.body);
    print(lampenstatus);
    return lampenstatus;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

Future lampoff() async {
  final response =
      await http.post(Uri.http(url, '/lampoff'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

With this switch and both functions (I've tried both with lampon) I can send my request to the API and the light goes on, but then the following error occurs and my Flutter app crashes:

```
unawaited(xhr.onError.first.then((_) {
  // Unfortunately, the underlying XMLHttpRequest API doesn't expose any
  // specific information about the error itself.
  completer.completeError(
      ClientException('XMLHttpRequest error.', request.url),
      StackTrace.current);
}));
```

Does somebody have a solution for it?

Here is my PythonCode:

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/lampon', methods=['GET','POST'])
def lamp_on():
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
        return jsonify({'Lampenstatus':True})

@app.route('/lampoff', methods=['GET','POST'])
def lamp_off():
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
        return jsonify({'Lampenstatus':False})



if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Is the API publicly accessible? Or can you share the API and a temporary credential to test the code?

Comment: I added the backend code to my question. Sorry, the API is not accessible via the internet.

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming the API is only accessible in your local envirenment. Do you get the expected response if you call the API via postman or a similar tool?

Comment: yes, the API gives me the intended answer there (bool 'Lampenstatus')